# C runtime error during recursive function call

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

So I have a program to find the total number of ways in which an integer N can be expressed as the sum of "n" integers.
For example, 10 can be expressed as a combination of 2,3 and 5 as follows-

10 = 5 + 5

10 = 5 + 3 + 2

10 = 3 + 3 + 2 + 2

10 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int ways(int,int*,int);


int main()    {
    int n,num; //n is number of possible integers 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int*curr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));     //dynamically allocated array that stores all "n" integers in array form
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)    {
        scanf("%d",curr+i); 
    }
    int t,N; //t is number of test cases
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)    {
        scanf("%d",&N);     //for each test case, scans the number N that needs to be expressed as a sum of combinations those "n" integers
        num=ways(N,curr,n);
        printf("%d\n",num);
    }
    return 0;
}

int ways(int N,int*p,int size) {
    int flag=1;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(N/(*(p+i))!=0)  {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
//Above loop says that if number N is less than all of the "n" integers, it 
cannot be expressed as their sum. Hence, 0 will be returned if flag is 1
    }
    if(flag==1)
        return 0;
    if(N==0)
        return 1;
    int num=0,temp;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        temp=*(p+i);
        num=num+ways(N-temp,p,size);  //GETTING RUNTIME ERROR AT THIS LINE
    }   
    return num;
}
```

The program is getting SIGSEGV error at the recursive function call even for very small depth of recursion

Comment: would be nice to give inputs that cause your crash... there are lots of scanf, we cannot guess for all of them...

Comment: All Inputs give crash as soon as we reach that particular line.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are expecting too much guessing for my taste. Would you like to at least explain all the values to input? Age? Weight? Number of "n"s?

Comment: ok wait, writing lot of explanatory comments

Comment: Don't write `*(p+i)`.  Just use `p[i]` instead.  Otherwise you're just making it painful to read.

Comment: @ShashankKumar Please remove all the I/O functions and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first `i` loop in `ways`, you seem to be looking for a value in
array `p` that is smaller than `N` (though division is a horribly
inefficient way to test). Having found one, you do other things, then
use another `i` loop, losing the value of `i` you found in the first
one, and call `ways` recursively.

Now, note that you do no testing in the second loop. It’s entirely
possible to subtract something from `N` that is larger than `N`, get a
negative result, and pass that. This would cause infinite recursion, no?

Comment: I think that's it.  It needs to check for `N - temp` < 0.  If sufficiently negative, the recursive call might produce a negative (hence non-zero) quotient in the initial check.

Comment: Thanks, runtime error has been solved by rerplacing if(flag==1) with if(flag==1||N<0)

Answer (score 0):

A SIGSEGV error is a Segmentation fault error, which means that you are trying to access a memory location out of your programs reach.
This is most common due to de-referencing a null pointer or going over in your for loop. Try checking the logic of your code.

I think when you are typing *(p + 1), you are going out of bounds at some point. Try debugging with breakpoints or by outputting the value of *(p+1) in the for loop.

Comment: It's more likely a stack overflow.

Comment: Error is not due to pointer dereferencing because i am getting the same error even in the case of a large size array